In How many ways we can Tile the nth stair system using only squares
Find out the Number of distinct ways to tile n - stair system using only squares.
Necessary points to be taken care of are :
You can use any dimension and any number of squares as you need to tile the staircase.
What is n - stair system
\begin{array}{l}
\blacksquare \quad \blacksquare \quad \blacksquare \\
\blacksquare \quad \blacksquare \\
\blacksquare \\
\end{array}
this is n=3 Stair just imagine it in form where there is no spacing between the boxes and joined together .
Denote the stair of order n as S(n).The above diagram is of S(3)
Till now i have been trying to solve it using recursion but i cant find out how to do it.
This is what i found that u can make square of lenght n by using S(n) + S(n-1) .This can be done by joining the below
\begin{array}{lcl}
\text{n = 3:} & \quad & \text{n = 2:} \\
\blacksquare \quad \blacksquare \quad \blacksquare & \quad & \blacksquare \quad \blacksquare \\
\blacksquare \quad \blacksquare & \quad & \blacksquare \\
\blacksquare & \quad & \\
\end{array}
now rotating S(2) by 180 degrees anticlockwise and join them to look like
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\blacksquare & \blacksquare & \blacksquare \\
\hline
\blacksquare & \blacksquare & \blacksquare \\
\hline
\blacksquare & \blacksquare & \blacksquare \\
\hline
\end{array}
I was trying to solve it by using recusion or combinatorics on n*n square that number of ways to get answer and subtracting the cases made by S(n-1) in total can someone please help me to find any recurrense relation or any formula?
number of ways denoted as f(S(n))
Some test cases answer is as follows
f(S(1)) and f(S(2)) is 1
f(S(3))=2
f(S(4))=4
f(S(5)) =14

Some computations yielded the sequence: 1,1,2,4,14,58,352,2860,32008. No hits on OEIS.

How did you get these numbers @MathieuRundström

I don't understand what you mean by "n stair system". Please be more explicit.

@JeanMarie please nth stair system is height of stair is n and i have written about it .

I am sorry but in your comment  "...is height of stair is n" is not an understable sentence.  The n-stair problem I find on the web is the number of ways to climb n steps with stepsizes 1 or 2...I don't think it is the same.

@jeanMarie I am so sorry about that you should see  https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F10-teacherrecommended-math-apps-and-online-tools--337558934577510257%2F&psig=AOvVaw3ZOY8HSukERVAcjUYTRddh&ust=1727528829531000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBQQjRxqFwoTCJCersSY44gDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAZ.  This link will show you stair where u can climb 2 ,3,4 steps respectively thus nth stair system is stair where u can climb n steps. I hope this is helpful

@Antarjot I wrote a dynamic programming Python script. So maybe there should be a recursive relation/formula.

@MathieuRundström please can you answer the question or can give me the code for it so that i can understand
